# What is a Chrome data compression proxy?

Tags: php, google-chrome, proxy

I am getting lots of clicks to my servers with headers like so:

```
HTTP_VIA:1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR:105.XXX.XX.XXX,66.249.93.214
HTTP_FORWARDED:for=105.XXX.XX.XXX
```

`66.249.93.214` is the ip that shows in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, while the 105 address is the real IP address of the visitor(I believe). An IP lookup of `66.249.93.214` shows a google proxy/data center.

Advertisers I work with are complaining that this traffic is bot traffic and should not be paid for. They are seeing thousands of clicks in the 66.249 range.

To me, it looks like some sort of chrome extension. Can anyone tell me what's happening here? And if this traffic is legitimate?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the tech lead for the Chrome Data Saver proxy. This is indeed legitimate traffic from users who have enabled the Data Saver feature in Chrome. Because the requests to your server will appear as though they are coming from Google's IP addresses, it doesn't surprise me that you are seeing a large volume of traffic from a narrow range of IPs. However, the X-Forwarded-For and Forwarded headers contain the IP address of the user accessing the proxy.

Let me know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I am pretty concerned with reading an IP from header information...since this can be spoofed/faked by anyone. Is there a way to verify that the IP is indeed from Google?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is pretty standard stuff used by proxies around the world, including those from Opera Mini and other popular browsers. The best way to verify the accuracy is to confirm that the requests are coming from Google's IP address ranges. See: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en

Comment: We have some validation in code based on ip detection. We need to whitelist this on nginx with set_real_ip_from. We would like to know the series for both ipv4 and ipv6 if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome for Android has a ["Data Saver" proxy](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284). This is likely what is sending the traffic you see, which is more than likely legitimate traffic. If you want to prevent users from accessing through this proxy, you can restrict traffic to HTTPS-only, which is preferable for other reasons anyway.